# Rule-Based Styling not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based

I'm trying to create a shapefile I can use as a template for a breeding bird survey. The basic gist was that each species has a two letter code and a colour depending on the BTO listing. Each bird is either red, amber or green. There would then be extra markers to say whether the bird was singing or calling etc. So, I set up an attribute table with a column labelled "BTO Code" and "Behaviour"

I then went ahead and set it up so that when you typed a species code into that column, it would set the point marker as those letters coloured either green, amber or red. At first it was working, I kept testing it as I went along and the points were showing up fine on the map. The markers for singing/calling were working fine too. Below is what shapefile and my rules looked like:

[image]

[image]

Well, I just finished adding the last few species, clicked apply and ALL my points disappeared. Now when I try to add a species, they appear in the attribute table but not the map!

I'm at a loss. This is my second attempt at creating this shapefile/styling and the same thing happened last time, last time I assumed it was something I had done wrong, and couldn't for the life of me figure out what it was so I just started again. I really don't have the will to do this all over again! I'm at my wits end. Please can someone with a bit more knowledge than me shed some light on why it would suddenly stop working when I've done everything right in the code?

All I can think is that there may be a limit to how many rules you can set when using rule-based styling? There are a lot of birds! I've looked online though and can't find anything regarding a limit to how many rules you can set.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is in QGIS!

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out how to write good questions. Please give further information on your expressions and include screenshots.

Comment: I have added screenshots showing expressions and what the styling did look like before they all disappeared

Comment: You could try to only create the behavioural rules and then `refine` these using a classification based on the species.

Comment: And save the style once in a while.

Comment: How do I refine them?

Comment: Click the button `refine current rules`.

Comment: Be sure to have the behavioural rules marked before refining anything.

Comment: I just don't know why it would suddenly stop working. The rules were working fine at first...

Comment: In your second screenshot, you seem to match "BTO Code" against species (AV=Avocet etc) and also list status ("BTO Code" = 'Red'/'Amb'). Not sure if this is your problem but seems odd. I would have thought "BTO Code" would always be species and another field would store the status...

Comment: That was just for the key on the composer for the map, not actually used in the coding. Which is why the letters are "XX". It's just to show people looking at the map that any yellow lettering denotes an amber listed species, and red lettered denotes red listed species etc etc.

I've set the colouring and the lettering as one. So when I type "AV" into the BTO Code box, the letters will come up yellow.